# run cgi file from shell script

Tags: bash, perl, shell, cgi-bin

I have a set of 20 shell script files, in cgi-bin when firest .sh file runs the next one is triggered at the end of each script. i want to execute a .cgi in browser after certain scripts. Any way to achieve it?

this is first sh file which is triggered

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
echo -n " Starting"
./1.script.sh
```

1.script runs in same way and triggers 2.script.sh and so on after running 6.script.sh i want cgi.cgi file to be executed in the browser.

Comment: you can't execute a cgi in the browser, cgi is serverside. I suggest you edit your question. Otherwise, the output of your subsequently triggered cgis will appear appended.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. It seems likely that if you took a step back and explained what you are trying to do at a higher level, then we could help you come up with a strategy for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `./cgi.cgi` after `./1.script.sh` ? If the second ... 6. scripts are all called inside 1.script.sh then after that call `cgi.cgi`; or I misunderstood something...

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
echo -n " Starting"
./1.script.sh
./cgi.cgi
```

Comment: i need to run cgi in browser

Comment: just repeating an impossible question won't help you get an answer I'm sorry. - if want the earth to rotate westward and want help I won't get it neither.